# Web worker not throws error after creation in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-worker

I can't understand whether there's something in sharepoint that that's causing 
my web worker to throw an error as soon as its created In IE11 . The same worker runs great on chrome. Even tried a simple test:

the worker file :

```
     self.addEventListener('message',function(e){  console.log("message");  })
```

and I'm creating the worker like so:

```
var worker = new Worker('http://{rootSite}/sites/53/Style%20Library/testworker.js')
worker.addEventListener('message',function(e){  console.log("message");  });
worker.addEventListener('error',function(e){  console.log("error");  });
```

It's strange because I tested the same script on a non sharepoint site and it worked on IE.

but on a sharepoint site as soon as create the test worker from the same site's doc library.. it throws an error.. with a null message !!

Please can anyone tell me what is going on here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question but I'd like to leave an answer for anyone who stumbles upon it.

Loading a Web worker via blob in IE has many limitations. Wouldn't recommend going down that route.

For some reason, Internet Explorer blocks Web workers from loading when the file is loaded from a sharepoint site.

Storing your Web worker files in the _layouts folder works well.

Comment: yes, that was it. Thank's for leaving an answer here!

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... So for all the share point developers who ever want to use web workers in their apps..

I still don't know why in internet explorer the web worker failed to load the external script

But apparently an inline web worker works !

So you could store you worker code in the doc library as a text file. And then get its content via ajax and then create an inline worker. You will need the window.URL object and the blob constructor :

First build a blob from the javascript code as a string:

```
Var string = "worker code ";
```

Var blob = new blob([ string] , {type:"text/javascript"});

Var worker = new Worker(URL.createUriObject(blob));